# Custom Access Calculated Field Function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to create a Custom Calculated Field Function For MS-Access. The reason being that there is no reason to run a query, and each row could possibly have two different results based on a field type. I have a function VBA Function. However I cannot use it to calculate a calculated field.

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Office 2010

## Code

### Key Types Enumeration

VBA

```
Public Enum KeyTypes
FullField = -1
RemoveSpaces = 0
FirstThreeLetters = 3
FirstFourLetters = 4
FirstLetterOfEachWord = 11
FirstTwoLettersOfEachWord = 22
CombineSubKeys = 2
End Enum
```

### Create Key Function

VBA

```
Public Function CreateKey(KeyType As KeyTypes, KeyString1 As String, Optional Delimiter As String = "", Optional KeyString2 As String = "") As String

Dim tmp() As String ' For Splitting String by Spaces in cases FirstLetterOfEachWord and FirstTwoLettersOfEachWord


'StrConv(KeyString1, VbProperCase) capitalizes the first letter of each word

Select Case KeyType

Case FullField ' if Return Full Field as key
CreateKey = KeyString1

Case CombineSubKeys ' If combine two keys with delimiter
CreateKey = KeyString1 & Delimiter & KeyString2

Case FirstThreeLetters ' Create Key From First 3 Letters Of String
CreateKey = Left(StrConv(KeyString1, vbProperCase), 3)

Case FirstFourLetters ' Create Key From First 4 Letters Of String
CreateKey = Left(StrConv(KeyString1, vbProperCase), 4)

Case FirstLetterOfEachWord ' Create Key From First Letter of Each Word In String

tmp = Split(StrConv(KeyString1, vbProperCase), " ")
CreateKey = ""
For Each KeyC In tmp
CreateKey = CreateKey & Left(KeyC, 1)
Next

Case FirstTwoLettersOfEachWord ' Create Key From FirstTwo Letters of Each Word In String
tmp = Split(StrConv(KeyString1, vbProperCase), " ")
CreateKey = ""
For Each KeyC In tmp
CreateKey = CreateKey & Left(KeyC, 2)
Next

Case RemoveSpaces ' Create Key String by Removing Spaces
CreateKey = Replace(KeyString1, " ", "")

Case Else ' If Invalid Key Type, Output KeyString1
CreateKey = FirstKeyString
End Select
End Function


End Function
```

## Tables

Data Set Structures are Bulleted Lists So I can list out the properties of the different fields.

### Key Types

Table Name is ***KeyTypes***

#### Data Set Structure

- Key

  - Text
- Enumeration

  - Number
  - Integer
  - Indexed (No Duplicates)
- Index

  - Number
  - Integer
  - Indexed (No Duplicates)

#### Data Set Example

| Key | Enumeration | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Full Field | -1 | 1 |
| Remove Spaces | 0 | 2 |
| First 3 Letters | 3 | 3 |
| First 4 Letters | 4 | 4 |
| First Letter of Each Word | 11 | 5 |
| First Two Letters Of Each Word | 22 | 6 |
| Combine SubKeys | 2 | 7 |

### Main Data

Table Name is ***MainData***

#### Main Data Set Structure

- Field 1

  - Text
- Field 2

  - Text
    -Field 1 Key Type
  - Number
  - Long Integer

    - 0 Decimal Places
  - Lookup = Combobox
    -Row Source (SQL)= `SELECT KeyTypes.Key, KeyTypes.Enumeration, KeyTypes.Index FROM KeyTypes ORDER BY KeyTypes.Index;`

    - Multiple Values= No
    - Bound Column =2
      -Field 2 Key Type
  - Number
  - Long Integer

    - 0 Decimal Places
  - Lookup = Combobox
    -Row Source (SQL)= `SELECT KeyTypes.Key, KeyTypes.Enumeration, KeyTypes.Index FROM KeyTypes ORDER BY KeyTypes.Index;`

    - Multiple Values= No
    - Bound Column =2
- Field 1 Key

  - Calculated

    - Expression: = `CreateKey([Field 1 Key Type],[Field 1])`
- Field 2 Key

  - Calculated

    - Expression: = `CreateKey([Field 2 Key Type],[Field 2])`
- Full Key

  - Calculated
    -Expression: = `CreateKey(2,[Field 1 Key],".",[Field 2 Key])

#### Main Data Set Example

| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 1 Key Type | Field 2 Key Type | Field 1 Key | Field 2 Key | Full Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hello | World | Full Field | Full Field | hello | World | hello.World |
| welcome to | programming | First Two Letters Of Each Word | First 4 Letters | WeTo | Prog | WeTo.Prog |
| Ready | World | First 4 Letters | First 3 Letters | Read | Wor | Read.Wor |
| Are You Ready To Begin | Programming | First Letter of Each Word | First 4 Letters | AYRTB | Prog | AYRTB.Prog |

## Current Output

### Error Message(s)

If I attempt to create an expression for the table column using the function when I save the table I get a message which says the following:

> The Expression CreateKey( [Field 1 Key Type] , [Field 1] ) cannot be used in a calculated column

Which is followed by another message:

> Errors were encountered during the save operation. Fields were not added. Properties were not updated.

Comment: You say "I cannot use it to calculate a calculated field". Why not? Are you getting an error. Are you getting something that you don't expect? Is something else happening besides an error/incorrect results?

Comment: It does not recognize my custom function in the expression builder. I will post what happens when I attempt to do it.

Comment: Cannot do in table calculated type field. Call the function from a query or textbox or another procedure.

Comment: _there is no reason to run a query_ ... well, there is.

Comment: I didn't mean there is no way, it is more accurate for what I am trying to do there is not really a point.

Comment: Ok, So the only way to do it is either through a query or a text box or a large amount of conditions. because ***iif*** and ***choose*** still work

Comment: Now you get it. But why are you so fixated on using Calculated type field? Why even calculate these "keys" - what is their purpose?

Comment: The key was for looking up some thing, with two parameters, but having a single identifier to prevent repetition, thus a calculated field to create a unique key. because both fields could reuse values. The reason to use calculated field was simply it was merely editing a string based on a switch case parameter. I didn't think a query was really necessary for that. Also this file is only for storing data, but not edit it directly. the data will be read and edited from an entirely different file. I can do this using ***IIF***, or ***Choose*** but would rather not (complicates the expression)

Comment: Just went with fields for each variation and a ***choose*** function in the final key.